# WP Как привязаться к посту который НЕ принадлежит категории?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть необходимость добавлять всем постам у которых нету категории со слагом `national-football-team` определенный css.

```
/ Для Обзора Команды
    if (is_single() && !is_category("national-football-team")):
        wp_enqueue_style('onlySingleFootballTeam', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/only_team-post.min.css', array('main-css'), null, false);
    endif;
```

А тем что имеют, другой....

```
    // Для Обзора Команды НАЦИОНАЛЬНОЙ сборной
    if  ( is_single() && is_category("national-football-team") ):
        wp_enqueue_style('onlyNationalFootballTeam', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/only_national-team.min.css', array('main-css'), null, false);
    endif;
```

Но это не работает. Не могу понять что не так с запросами.

Comment: [is_category()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_category) проверяет показывается ли страница категорий или нет. При помощи проверки `!is_category("national-football-team")` Вы по-сути проверяете не находитесь ли Вы на странице категории со слагом `"national-football-team"`

Comment: ок, понял. А есть ли способ добавлять стили постам в зависимости от назначенной категории ? Ну или заданного `Template Name:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[is_category()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_category) проверяет показывается ли страница категорий или нет. При помощи проверки `!is_category("national-football-team")` Вы по-сути проверяете не находитесь ли Вы на странице категории со слагом `"national-football-team"`. То есть работать оно будет только на странице категории.

Для своих целей Вы можете использовать [has_category()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/has_category)

```
if (is_single() && !has_category("national-football-team", get_the_ID())):
    wp_enqueue_style('onlySingleFootballTeam', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/only_team-post.min.css', array('main-css'), null, false);
endif;

if  (is_single() && has_category("national-football-team", get_the_ID()) ):
    wp_enqueue_style('onlyNationalFootballTeam', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/only_national-team.min.css', array('main-css'), null, false);
endif;
```

Если нужно добавить стили для конкретного `template` используйте [is_page_template()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_page_template), например `is_page_template('templates/template-file-name.php')`.

С версии WordPress 4.7 работатет с любыми пост тайпами, не только страницами.